# How should I write PHP $_POST variable in a mysql_query function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Simple question. How do i make the query work? I know you can't directly use `$_POST` in a query. But i do not know how to get this to work.

```
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = $_POST[password] AND `username` = $_POST[username]';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($link);
exit;
```

I have also tried using the mysqli_real_escape_string like this :

```
    $username_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
    $password_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
```

This did not work as planned. As it did still not work.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: As you're already using MySQLi, you should do it using [prepared statements/bind variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php).... you should not be injecting user-entered values directly into an SQL query string

Comment: And you certainly should not be storing plaintext passwords in your database.... use PHP's built-in [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)/[password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).... learn the correct way to do this now, and you won't need to re-learn it again later

Comment: Use prepared statements please!

Comment: @MarkBaker , i know you should not store plaintext. It's just a small school assignment which is about sessions. Only making this to be able to learn about sessions.

Comment: @mike - my point is that learning bad habits when you're just starting out, it's a lot harder to unlearn them and learn good habits later.... learning good habits (such as the use of prepared statements) now will stand you in better stead in the coming months/years

Comment: @MarkBaker Alright, you have a point there. Will change my way of programming from now on. Thanks.

Comment: NEVER TRUST USER INPUT!

Comment: and the final advice, use PDO instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `''` with string comparison of MySQL

```
$username_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']);
$password_sql = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE `password` = '$username_sql' AND `username` = '$password_sql'";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Would you mind telling me what i did wrong? So i will not make this mistake anymore.

Comment: use **''** with string comparison of MySQL @mike

Comment: if my answer helps you please accept my answer @mike

Comment: I suggest to use prepared statements

Answer (score 4):

Use prepared statements to avoid sql injection and syntax errors with commas .

```
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = ? AND `username` = ?';

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['password'], $_POST['username']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result){
    echo $row['username'] .'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it is necessary to add at least one example of prepared statements, just to show that it is not more difficult and it makes your application safer (SQL-injection).

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = ? AND `username` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST[password], $_POST[username]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();
// read the result...
$stmt->close();
```

Be aware that passwords should not be stored plain text, instead one should use the functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question yourself.
mysqli_real_escape_string() is the way to go.

```
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE `password` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[password]) . '" AND `username` = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[username]') . '"';
```

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() hasn't been the way to go for a long while, prepared statements/bind variables are the way to go